# "pointer-events: none" on range-input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to develop a range-input with from-to-values and used this as a basic:

**Codepen Link:** https://codepen.io/Manitoba/pen/ZWRjye?editors=1111

```css
body {
  background-color: #666;
  margin: 100px 50px;
}

[slider] {
  position: relative;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 45px 0 10px 0;
}

[slider] > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 14px;
}

[slider] > div > [inverse-left] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 7px;
}

[slider] > div > [inverse-right] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 7px;
}

[slider] > div > [range] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
}

[slider] > div > [thumb] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
}

[slider] > input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 14px;
  top: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: transparent;
  border: transparent;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: red;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: red;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: red;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}

[slider] > div > [sign] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -11px;
  top: -39px;
  z-index:3;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
  color: #fff;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

[slider] > div > [sign]:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 16px;
  top: 19px;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-top-width: 16px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #1ABC9C;
}

[slider] > div > [sign] > span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 28px;
}

[slider]:hover > div > [sign] {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div slider id="slider-distance">
  <div>
    <div inverse-left style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div inverse-right style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div range style="left:30%;right:40%;"></div>
    <span thumb style="left:30%;"></span>
    <span thumb style="left:60%;"></span>
    <div sign style="left:30%;">
      <span id="value">30</span>
    </div>
    <div sign style="left:60%;">
      <span id="value">60</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="range" tabindex="0" value="30" max="100" min="0" step="1" oninput="
  this.value=Math.min(this.value,this.parentNode.childNodes[5].value-1);
  var value=(100/(parseInt(this.max)-parseInt(this.min)))*parseInt(this.value)-(100/(parseInt(this.max)-parseInt(this.min)))*parseInt(this.min);
  var children = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes;
  children[1].style.width=value+'%';
  children[5].style.left=value+'%';
  children[7].style.left=value+'%';children[11].style.left=value+'%';
  children[11].childNodes[1].innerHTML=this.value;" />

  <input type="range" tabindex="0" value="60" max="100" min="0" step="1" oninput="
  this.value=Math.max(this.value,this.parentNode.childNodes[3].value-(-1));
  var value=(100/(parseInt(this.max)-parseInt(this.min)))*parseInt(this.value)-(100/(parseInt(this.max)-parseInt(this.min)))*parseInt(this.min);
  var children = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes;
  children[3].style.width=(100-value)+'%';
  children[5].style.right=(100-value)+'%';
  children[9].style.left=value+'%';children[13].style.left=value+'%';
  children[13].childNodes[1].innerHTML=this.value;" />
</div>
```

It works great However except in MS IE and Edge, I can't drag the thumbs. I believe it's due to:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

on the actual range-input.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look: [`Alternatives to “pointer-events:none” in IE?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494011/alternatives-to-pointer-eventsnone-in-ie)

Comment: thanks @Alex, I looked at that, however I can't get it to work anyway... you can fork the above example if you want! :)

Comment: What IE version you running?

Comment: it needs to run from IE11 upwards

Comment: But [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) mentions its supported

Comment: @VigneshRaja so any other idea why it isn't working?

Comment: Please include the code within your question, don't just link to it.

Comment: this might help you [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie)

Comment: This works on my version of Microsoft Edge. Nothing is broken.

Comment: Works for me, not reproducible

Answer (score 0):

In this line remove `value="30"`, then it works, you set the range value to 30, so whenever we try to change the value, an event will occur, but the value doesn't change so, it does not reflect on UI.